# extracting values from a table with specific color attribute using HTMLAgilitypack

Tags: html, parsing, xpath, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to extract a table on a webpage that has a red color for months with data.  I've tried using an XPath with `//font[@color='#ff0000']` which returns the months I want but I lose the year of those months.  I'm thinking I would have to extract the months row by row and appending the year to the months.  I may be missing something because I'm new to using HTMLAgilitypack.  The table is from http://www.raws.dri.edu/cgi-bin/rawNAME.pl?idIAN1

```
<td> <b> 2014 </b> </td> 
<td><font color=\"#ff0000\"> <b> Jan </b></font> </td>
<td><font color=\"#ff0000\"> <b> Feb </b></font> </td> 
<td><font color=\"#ff0000\"> <b> Mar </b></font> </td> 
<td> Apr  </td> 
<td> May  </td> 
<td> Jun  </td> 
<td> Jul  </td> 
<td> Aug  </td> 
<td> Sep  </td> 
<td> Oct  </td> 
<td> Nov  </td> 
<td> Dec  </td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass that condition as a predicate, i.e. with XPath like:

```
//td[font[@color='#ff0000']]
```

Or you could traverse to the ParentNode of the nodes returned by your current XPath...

Comment: the year isn't the parent though.  it's a sibling of the months.

Comment: Rowland Shaw you're right, //td[font[@color='#ff0000']] as a predicate then traversing to the parent node and returning it's first child would give me the year.